# Autosave but only for a specific file in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to automatically save only a specific file in VSCode. Is that possible?

The closest I could find on the net is the discussion around implementing autoSave on language specific file. But that's a different usecase.

Comment: If you build (compile) something in VSC, it may save files automatically.

Comment: thanks @puio, but that's different case.

Comment: just to reach closure for autosave on language-specific file (you mention it but didn't link to a solution) : https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/42170

Comment: aw, darn, it didn't get implemented